# How to get a method param name array/list in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, parameters, rtti

Is there any way to get the names of the parameters of a given method of a class/object in an array/delimited string in Delphi 7? Somehow like this:

```
var
  s : string;
  aSL : TStringList;
begin
  ...
  // using rtti calls in TMethodUtility.collectParamNames
  s := TMethodUtility.collectParamNames( TStringList.addObject );
  // or
  TMethodUtility.collectParamNames( TStringList.addObject, aSL );
  ...
end;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no `AddItem()` method in `TString/List`. There is `Add()` and `AddObject()` instead.

Comment: OK. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is technically possible (otherwise the IDE's Form Designer could not generate code for component event handlers at design-time), however, there are important caveats that will hinder your goal (and make the particular example in your question impossible to resolve):

- the necessary RTTI is only generated for *properties* that are declared as `published` (such as component events).  RTTI is not generated for methods themselves (even `published` ones), or for properties that are not `published`.
- `TObject` has a public `MethodAddress()` method for getting the memory address of a `published` method (the DFM streaming system uses this when hooking up event handlers), however you cannot get the necessary RTTI from a method pointer alone.

*IF* you can match a given method pointer to the *value* of a `published` event, then you can extract the parameter names from the event's RTTI.  Obtain a `TypInfo.PPropInfo` pointer for the event using the `TypInfo.GetPropInfo()` function, then pass its `PropType` field value to the `TypInfo.GetTypeData()` function to get a `TypInfo.PTypeData` pointer, and then you can iterate through its `ParamList` field (which is an array of records containing `ParamName` and `TypeName` fields).

See the following blog article on this topic for more details:

[Getting the parameters of published methods](http://hallvards.blogspot.com/2006/05/hack-10-getting-parameters-of.html).

For what you are attempting, a general-purpose solution would require [**Extended RTTI**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Working_with_RTTI_Index) that was introduced in Delphi 2010 and thus is not available in Delphi 7.  Extended RTTI is not limited to `published` items, and is *much* more detailed than what the old-style RTTI provides.